# How do I convert image colour temperature in a calibrated way?

Tags: python, colors, color-space, color-theory

How do you adjust an image in a calibrated RGB colour space to have a specific colour temperature, using the [colour](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html) Python library or similar?

I have an image that has been captured in uncalibrated 16-bit linear RGB space and then calibrated in the ProPhoto RGB colour space using a colour checker included in the image. This is done by mapping the manufacturer-supplied colour target values from L*a*b* to ProPhoto RGB, detecting the corresponding source colours in the input image calibration card, and then applying the [colour.colour_correction](https://colour.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/colour.colour_correction.html#colour.colour_correction) function.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38889696/3024114) describes how to calculate the colour temperature of a "white" RGB value, and I can do the following to find that the colour temperature of the white reference in the image is currently 6250 k:

```
import colour

ref_gray = [0.85007768, 0.89948808, 1.11035624]

XYZ = colour.RGB_to_XYZ(ref_gray, "ProPhoto RGB")
xy = colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ)
CCT = colour.xy_to_CCT(xy, method="hernandez1999")

# CCT is 6250.9622746435989
```

There is also a `colour.CCT_to_xy` function that will go the other direction, but I don't know how you would use the resulting xy chromaticity coordinates to adjust the image or whether it even makes sense to talk about doing so.

How can the image be adjusted so that the white tile has a colour temperature of 5500 k instead?

Comment: Your reference gray, i.e. `[0.85007768, 0.89948808, 1.11035624]`, is not neutralised. It is blueish which means that if you chromatically adapt to **D55**, you will still have some of that bluish cast still present in the image. To avoid that, you could first neutralise the image by dividing it by your reference gray and then do the chromatic adaptation from ProPhoto RGB whitepoint to D55.