# How to get the current color temperature of the camera in real time？

Tags: android, camera, temperature, cct

I need to implement the light source matching function of Sidus Link APP.

The function is to open the camera preview and display the color temperature in real time.
This is the related picture of the function：
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4UAp.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6oUK.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTV90.png)

I don’t have any ideas, and I don’t know what to calculate the temperature.
It is not like calculating by getting the color of the middle white box, nor is it like getting the real-time color temperature of the camera directly (not sure if there is a corresponding API)

So I want to ask if anyone has done a similar function, please help me with some ideas or suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Related: [How to get Color Temperature from Color Correction Gain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45433647/295004)